# Customizing image of grabbed item

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a mouse area which I grab and save into image after click on it.

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    objectName: "testMouseArea"
    width: 64;
    height: 64
    onPressed: tile.grabToImage(function (result) {
        result.saveToFile("D:/ouput.png")
    });
    Rectangle {
        id: tile
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

Before saving I want to change opacity of grabbed image of the mouse area.

I've added

```
result.image.opacity = 0.5
```

before saving, but it doesn't help. Output files have the same opacity (no effect at all).

Comment: `MouseArea` is not visible so what do you try to save? what is `result.image.opacity`? As I see image is `var`, that has no properties. Even it is `QImage ` that still has no `opacity` property. I advice you to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you expect to get an answer. Another tip is to avoid using `this` since this is fraught with mistakes and use `id` instead.

Comment: @folibis I've update the code. In my mouse area there's a blue rectangle. The question is how to change opacity of image I get from result as variant according to the doc https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-itemgrabresult.html#image-prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the best way is to set opacity to the saved `Item` and then grab the image. If for some reason you want to do more with the image so that all about `QImage` processing. You can create custom C++ item, probably singleton, or regular QML item with appropriate method:

```
bool ImageProcess::saveWithOpacity(const QImage &input, const QString &path, double opacity)
{
    QImage image(input.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    image.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter p(&image);
    p.setOpacity(opacity);
    p.drawImage(0, 0, input);
    p.end();
    return image.save(path);
}
```

and then you can use that in QML code:

```
MouseArea {
    id: area
    ...
    onClicked: {
        area.grabToImage(function (result) {
            imgProcess.saveWithOpacity(result.image, "/path/to/file/img.png", 0.5);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```